# Why can't I export this schema?

Tags: oracle, export, dump

This is strictly a test system.
Command I'm executing is:

```
expdp XXXXX/XXXXX schemas=someSchema directory=DUMPDIR dumpfile=dump.dmp logfile=explog.txt
```

Environment settings:

```
ORACLE_SID=ORCL
ORACLE_HOME=/.../dbhome
```

Error seen is:

```
UDE-12546: operation generated ORACLE error 12546
ORA-12546: TNS:permission denied
```

Mystifying since I was testing it with the root user on the OS and the system user on the Database. Clearly there is something very basic wrong somewhere.

This is running in a docker container.

Comment: Apparently it's because I need to use the Oracle user to do it.

Comment: Never do anything with oracle as the root user.  In fact, never do ANYTHING as root that does not absolutely require it.  Get out of that nasty habit now.

Comment: perhaps you could try with a correct connection string, as root, you are not sourcing oracle's profile, so necessary oracle environment variables are missing. Do it preferably as oracle, but if you must as root, at-least source the right environment variables.

Comment: @EdStevens While I agree with you in principle and never use root on my Linux systems, you make the mistake of assuming that I have a choice at work.  There is no other admin user on these test systems. They get blown away periodically anyway. If this were a non-test system, I'd go through channels and have a DBA do it.

Comment: @user447607, if you have root access, then you DO have a choice. If nothing else, you can always su to the required account.

Comment: @EdStevens You are confused. On the one hand we are talking about Linux systems and on the other about Oracle. It is Oracle I don't have a choice regarding and this is because the configuration is shared.

Comment: @user447607 - so exactly what do YOU mean by "the oracle user" and "the system user".  The os has accounts (usernames) and the database has accounts (usernames) what are you using for each, and exactly why do you think you don't have access to one or the other?  I cannot reproduce your error but I'm highly suspicious of a 'tns' error when nothing about the connect string (at least obfuscated one you show) would indicate a tns connection.